# How to check what variables exist in current python environment/workspace

Tags: python

Is that possible to check what variables or instance of any classes exist in the current python workspace/environment? can I use any functions to list them?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: `dir()` will give you a list of all modules, variables classes, functions etc. `globals()` and `locals()` give a dictionary, enabling you to access their values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer is at least 30 characters, and most definitely not 9, therefore I can submit this.

```
globals()
```